# How to draw chart using data in ViewBag in .net MVC5

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I have a table Trailers which contain trailers and the number of views of a trailer.Here i passed data from table Trailers to view using ViewBag and i want to draw a google chart using this data in viewbag but i have no idea about how to convert datas in viewbag to array required to draw chart in javascript

Here is the code used in javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Task', 'Views per Day'],
            @foreach(var t in ViewBag.trailer)
            {              
          [t.mov_name, t.count],
            }
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'My Daily Activities',
            pieHole: 0.4,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

I don'know how to insert datas in ViewBag to the variable data.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below

```
var trailers = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.trailer);
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(['Task', 'Views per Day'], trailers);
```

May be you need to properly manipulate trailer object before passing it to parameter.

Html.Raw() will resolve your issue.

Comment: showing error in the line var trailers = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.trailer);